# Login to oracle db failing

Tags: linux, oracle, database-connection

I am trying to login into the database and the following error is coming up.

[image: Login Issue]

On searching I found that there is no space available as shown below:

[image]

The issue is I am not able to login into the database to resolve this problem. I am able to login into the Linux machine where oracle server is installed but logging in as a DBA is not happening. For that, I tried `sqlplus / as sysdba` but the same issue is coming up as shown in the first picture.
I think this might be an issue of a lot of archive logs but I don't understand how do I check archive logs without having access to database. Following are my questions:
1. If archivelogs is the actual issue, how can we delete all the logs from the Linux machine without getting access to the database? Also how would we disable the generation of archive logs?
2. If this is not a correct solution, how would this issue be solved?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First things, first. Clear up some space on your `/` partition. The error is complaining exactly that!!

Answer (score 1):

You say you can log in to the server and your screenshot shows you know where the space is being used. Something like `sudo cd / && du -sh|sort -h` will show you where the space is being allocated. Using `du -sh` and navigating directories will then give you an idea of where most of the space is being used and hopefully allow you to delete some logs. Try `/var/log` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the above commands. I tried to find out the allocated memory, `/var/log` hardly contains anything to be worried about. It has taken 104M space only. I came across redo files in the machine but still couldn't find the archive files. Is there any particular path where the archives are stored?